# Python/pandas For Loop with Excel, Merge multiple Workbooks (Single Column) to Search List

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops

> I can get this working on Excel VBA but not python...

Appreciate if someone can help! This is what I have so far.

## Column name "Search" is the common index which I'm merging off.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

l = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"D:/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
             l.append(os.path.join(root, file))


search = 'Search List.xlsx'
source = pd.read_excel(open(search,'rb'), sheet_name=0)
source.set_index("Search", inplace = True)


for i in range(0, len(l)):
    path = l[i]
    df = pd.read_excel(open(path,'rb'), sheet_name=0)
    df.rename(columns={ df.columns[3]: "Search" }, inplace = True)
    df.set_index("Search",inplace = True)

final = pd.merge(source, df, on = ['Search'], how = 'left')
```

Os.walk gives me a the path of the files ending with xlsx, and creates a list?

---

['D:/Search\Find List 1.xlsx',
 'D:/Search\Find List 2.xlsx',
 'D:/Search\Find List 3.xlsx',
 'D:/Search\Find List 4.xlsx']

---

Once I have the path list, I need to open one at a time, Merge with the "Source" List matching the Column Search. One by one, i need merge the remaining excel file. Does this make sense?

How do I for loop read excel, merge the Columns that match and then move onto the next iteration of the list.

I am so damn confused

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I assume all the other files, except the source list, have the same number of columns and names. I would suggest you read in all those files, combine them, and finally merge with the source file. pd.concat([all the other files]), then source.merge(bla, left_on=..., right_on='search') this might help a bit: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html#data-in-out

Comment: Hi Sammy. Thanks for your input and the link. I went through and found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

> Found the solution after Sammy's suggestion. I concat all the Excel files in the list, then I adjusted the data as neccessary before merging with the original search list.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

l = []


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"D:/Search"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):

                df = pd.read_excel(open(file,'rb'), sheet_name=0, header = 0)
                df.rename(columns={ df.columns[3]: "Search" }, inplace = True)
                df["Path"] = file
                l.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(l, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame = frame.drop([frame.columns[0] , frame.columns[1], frame.columns[2], frame.columns[4]],  axis='columns')
frame.set_index("Search",inplace = True)


search = 'Search List.xlsx'
source = pd.read_excel(open(search,'rb'), sheet_name=0)
source.set_index("Search", inplace = True)



final = pd.merge(source, frame, on = ['Search'], how = 'left')
```